# Svr.sys should be running

Tags: windows-server-2012

BPA on my server gives me this result...

[image]

Why is the BPA saying that Server service isn't running,w hen it's running. Is it a bug in BPA or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I've checked that the Server service is running - and it's running. Now I don't know what more to try.

Comment: Seen this?  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21104.srv-sys-should-be-set-to-start-on-demand.aspx

Comment: @BradBouchard: I tried it, but BPA still says it's not running. Must be a bug in BPA.

Answer (score 0):

[location of original source for the below registry key](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/126912-srv-sys-warning-on-windows-2012-r2-best-practices-analyzer-bpa)

To restore the access of XP/2003 clients over SMB to the file servers/domain controllers on Windows Server 2012 R2, you can activate SMB 1 support through the registry.
To enable SMB 1.0 support in Windows Server 2012 R2, open the Registry Editor, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer and change the value of DependOnService from "SamSS Srv2" to "SamSS Srv".

Think im just going to ignore it on my side vs enable smb1 for an os that we do not support.

I found this [link](http://woshub.com/smb-1-0-support-in-windows-server-2012-r2/) also that explains how to remove sm1 with   a quick powershell command. Remove-WindowsFeature FS-SMB1

not sure if this helped. still checking on it.

Comment: How does your answer relate to the question?